# Cannot retrieve specific data from django?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm trying to create a simple page containing 1 video and as many comments as it has and each comment replies

I basically created three models, one for Video, one for comment and one for reply. then I tried to retrieve the data in the view file.

I successfully retrieved video and comments but failed to retrieve replies of each comment.

I'm using django 1.10.4

models.py

```
class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    embed_code = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey("Category", null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    free_preview = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    share_message = models.CharField(max_length=150, default=default_share_message)

    objects = models.Manager()
    # activemodel = ActiveModel()
    featuresandactive = Features()
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('slug', 'category')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        try:
            return reverse('video_detail', kwargs={'vid_slug':self.slug, 'cat_slug':self.category.slug})
        except:
            return "/"


class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=350)
    video = models.ForeignKey(Video, null=True, blank=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    Timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)


    objects = CommentManager()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text


class Reply(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser)
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment,null=True, blank=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    Timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)


    objects = ReplyManager()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

views.py

```
def video_detail(request, cat_slug, vid_slug):

    cat = Category.objects.get(slug=cat_slug)
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(video=obj)
    replys = Reply.objects.filter(comment=comments)

    context = {

    "cat": cat,
    "obj":obj,
    "comments":comments,
    "replys":replys,

    }
    return render(request, 'video_detail.html', context)
```

this is another view.py 
I tried this also but didn't work

```
def video_detail(request, cat_slug, vid_slug):

    cat = Category.objects.get(slug=cat_slug)

    obj = Video.objects.get(slug=vid_slug)

    comments = obj.comment_set.all()

    replys = comments.reply_set.all()

    context = {

    "cat": cat,
    "obj":obj,
    "comments":comments,
    "replys":replys
    }
    return render(request, 'video_detail.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
comments = Comment.objects.filter(video=obj)
```

'comments' contains a QuerySet. What you want to do next is ask for every Reply with a comment that's on that QuerySet, instead of comparing using '=':

```
replies = Reply.objects.filter(comment__in=comments)
```

relevant documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in

edit: changed it to 'replies' instead of 'replys'

edit2: added docs link

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm trying to loop through the comments and replies but it keeps giving me the total amount of replies to each comment. any help with that is totally appreciated.